# Voice feedback loop into the headphones

Tags: headphones

Is there a way on a Mac to have the input from the microphone be played in the headphones so I can listen to my own voice? Talking when you can't listen to yourself is a bit awkward

Comment: Without a true hardware solution, you are likely to suffer from latency - probably worse than not hearing yourself at all.

Answer (score 1):

There's always [LineIn](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/freebies/) *(I'm not the developer)*, which allows you to route audio from different inputs to different outputs as you choose.

The setup for routing audio from the microphone (or any other input source) to the speakers is as follows:

[image: 2]

To start or stop audio routing, click the <kbd>Play Thru</kbd> button.

Answer (score 1):

Head into QuickTime Player, go to File menu then New Audio Recording. Now there will be a sound slider on the bottom. Drag that slider all the way up to turn on full volume. Now click on the arrow beside the record button and make sure the microphone is selected. Now everything you said will go into QT Player and routed out into the headphone. Note that you don't have to click the record button for this to work.